# RadComboBox with Checkbox enabled - Persists last selected item text

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I have developed a user control which has only a RadComboBox with checkbox enabled in it. The problem that I am facing in my pages is, whenever I deselect all the checkbox items with in the RadComboBox and on close of it, the last selected item is displayed in its text section. I am not finding a way to fix it.

In the ideal scenario, if nothing / everything is selected, I am defaulting to the text "All". If any item is selected, the item text is displayed. Can some one help me, if I have to do any specific check to fix this problem?

I am sharing a animated GIF for my issue below.

[image]

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: What is your version of RadControls? I cannot reproduce the problem in the online demos: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue. But I solved as following.

Creative a property in your userControl as:

```
public string OnClientItemChecked {
    set { ddlControID.OnClientItemChecked = value; }
}
```

on aspx:

```
<uc1:TagName ID="ddlControlID" runat="server" OnClientItemChecked="ClearValue" />
```

on script tag:

```
    function ClearValue(sender, eventArgs) {
        var combobox = sender;
        var value = combobox._checkedIndices.toString();
        if (value == "") {
            combobox.clearSelection();
            combobox.set_emptyMessage(combobox.get_emptyMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

on aspx:

Do `AllowCustomText="True"` in your `RadComboBox`.